# Filter out breaks based on stack trace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to break in a function, but only if it was NOT called from a specific other function. That's because there's one or two functions that amount for most of the calls, but I'm not interested in debugging them.

I noticed that breakpoints have a *Filter* option:

[image: Screenshot showing a filter option in dropdown menu]

Is that something that could be used to filter stack trace and break based on it's contents?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use the filters for that, based on this: [Use breakpoints in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) Specifically, the breakpoint filters are meant for concurrent programs, and you can filter on:
MachineName, ProcessId, ProcessName, ThreadId, or ThreadName.

One suggestion I would make to get something like what you want, is to add an extra parameter with a default value to the function you want to break in. Then set the value to something different in the places you don't want to monitor, and use a "Conditional Expression" in the breakpoint to make it only break on the default value.

Of course, this requires you to make debugging-only changes to your code (and then revert them when done), so it is a pretty ugly approach.

Comment: Yeah, currently I'm using manual instrumentation, like commenting out other calls in the program, creating same function with different name etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the address of the code location where the function is called from, you could make the breakpoint condition depend on the return address stored on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Therefore, you should be able to set the breakpoint as a condition of the value `*(DWORD*)ESP` (32-bit code) or `*(QWORD*)RSP` (64-bit code). I haven't tested it though.

However, my above example will only work if the breakpoint is set at the very start of the function, before the called function pushes any values on the stack or modifies the stack pointer. I'm not sure where Visual Studio sets the breakpoint if you place it on the first instruction of a function. Therefore, you may have to either set the breakpoint in the disassembly window to the first assembler instruction of the function or you might have to compensate for the function having modified the stack pointer in the [function prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

Alternatively, if a proper [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) has been set up using the EBP register (or RBP for 64-bit), then you could use that instead.

Please note that not the address of the CALL instructon will be placed on the stack, but rather the return address, which is the address of the next assembler-level instruction of the calling function.

I suggest you first set an unconditional breakpoint where you want it and then inspect the stack using the memory viewer in the debugger, specifically to see where the values of ESP/RSP and EBP/RBP are pointing and where the return address is stored on the stack.

Comment: It is possible to put breakpoint at the very start, before arguments are initialized. But what you describe is beyound my skill and also my problem is that there is oftern several calls between the source that I want to debug and the function where I want to stop. Otherwise I could break in the source, but that forces me to do several jump-in steps.